# startActivityForResult not triggering onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-activity, camera, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult

I'm trying to make a simple app that that uses the phone camera so I followed this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) 
Basically I have a fab that on click launches the camera and this is the result:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0Xde.png)

It launches the camera as it should...

If I close the camera it prints "REQUEST_PHOTO" and "ACTIVITY FINISHED" but if I take a picture and then hit the right button to accept it nothing happens. The button doesn't work and the method onActivityResult isn't called.

Here you can see the relevant part of the code with the Logs in the onActivityResult method:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ...

        if(hasCamera()) {
            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    launchCamera();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    ...

   private void launchCamera() {

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        ...
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            ...
            photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile( ... );

            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO:
                Log.d("DEBUG", "REQUEST_PHOTO");
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Log.d("DEBUG", "REQUEST_PHOTO RESULT_OK");
                }
                break;
        }

        Log.d("DEBUG", "ACTIVITY FINISHED");
    }
}
```

Not only I'm not understanding why the method is not being called and the accept button is "blocked" but I also can't understand why the method is called only when the exit button is pressed.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of device you are testing this code. Hope you got all the necessary permission as marshmallow version onwards there are couple of dangerous permission which must be granted by the user.

Comment: Have you created the file before passing its URI to the camera application?

Comment: @makovkastar I've created the file just as the [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) said to do (createImageFile() function)

Answer (score 0):

If a file doesn't exists the Camera activity will not return. This is the one case.

Comment: Yes this may be one of the case.

Comment: If you are directly referring a File inside a Folder which you've not created before calling.. this may also cause such issue. In this case first call create Folder first.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give  permission for accessing camera

`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>`

i think you are using emulator for testing please use real device.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this Your problem will be solve:**

```
 if(hasCamera()) {
            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   Intent chooseImageIntent = ImagePicker.getPickImageIntent(YourActivity.this);

                    startActivityForResult(chooseImageIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
                }
            });

  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO:
                Log.d("DEBUG", "REQUEST_PHOTO");
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    bm = ImagePicker.getImageFromResult(this, resultCode, data);
                if (bm != null) {
                    bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm,256,256, true);

                    upload_img.setImageBitmap(bm);
                }
                }
                break;
        }

        Log.d("DEBUG", "ACTIVITY FINISHED");
    }
```